# Python - execute several commands in one process

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use Python to execute several commands with one process, but it does not work. When the first command is done it should continue with next but in this case, it stops. If I type exit then the next command is executed.

How can I get the commands to be executed after each other in same process. It's a bad example below but but want to make it easy.

```
import subprocess

CMD = "ls -l"
INIT = "sh"

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    p = subprocess.Popen(INIT, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    print(p.returncode)
    p = subprocess.call(CMD, shell=True)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sh` command is not complete until you type 'exit' in the interactive shell opened.  The Windows equivalent is `cmd`, which also exits when `exit` is entered.  To run multiple commands without user input, you must run commands that do not require user input.

Also, you should not send output to a pipe unless you read the other end.  If the pipe gets full, the subprocess will hang waiting for it to be emptied.  Use /dev/null to ignore output.